# Unzip multiple password protected files

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in python. I'm trying to write a simple python script to unzip multiple password protected files in a directory. Passwords are stored in a text file.

This is what i have come up with,

```
import subprocess
import os

currentFile = __file__
realPath = os.path.realpath(currentFile)
dirPath = os.path.dirname(realPath)
dirName = os.path.basename(dirPath)

sevenz = dirPath + '/binaries/7z.exe'
files = []

for filename in os.listdir():
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower()
    if ext == '.rar':
        files.append(filename)
    if ext == '.zip':
        files.append(filename)
    if ext == '.7z':
        files.append(filename)
    if ext == '7z.001':
        files.append(filename)           

with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
  passwords = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

for password in passwords:
    for file in files:
        subprocess.run([sevenz, 'x', '-y', '-p', password, file])
```

And below is the content of passwords.txt file,

```
zip
7z
rar
```

Running above code gives this error,

```
7-Zip 21.07 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2021-12-26

Scanning the drive for archives:

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
zip
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the args are wrong? It's treating `rar` as file name instead of password?

Comment: I'm more concerned with Lord Vader storing passwords in clear text

Comment: This script is going to try to unzip every file with every password. Shouldn't you stop trying to unzip a file once you find the correct password for it?

Comment: FYI, there's a Python library for reading 7zip archives, so you don't need to use subprocess: https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr

Comment: @Ganesh Kathiresan There are bunch of files i downloaded from the internet. I'm just trying to make the unzip process a bit easier. So, security is not my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password should be concatenated to `-p`, not a separate argument.

```
        subprocess.run([sevenz, 'x', '-y', '-p'+password, file])
```

Comment: Now it gives this error, `Extracting archive: test3.7z
--
Path = test3.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 90
Headers Size = 90
Solid = -
Blocks = 0

ERROR: Cannot open output file : Access is denied. : .\7z.txt

Sub items Errors: 1

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 1`

Comment: Because you're using the wrong password. There are 3 passwords in the text file, only one of them can be correct. You'll get errors for the others.

Comment: Actually, the error is about the output file. You don't have write permission to the current directory, or the 7z.txt file already exists and you don't have permission to overwrite it.

Comment: But, once the correct password is found, it should do the thing right? I tried running cmd as administrator and it still gives the error. And also there is no existing 7z.txt file.

Comment: If there's no existing file, then the problem is directory permissions.

Comment: Yeah you were right, the error was caused by directory permissions. Now the error is gone. Thanks for your support!